# Запятая перед «и только»

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Нужно писать *кеш*(,) и только *кеш*: *э* очень нечасто после согласных пишется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Нужно писать кеш, **и только кеш**: э очень нечасто после согласных пишется.*

[Правило Розенталя:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105#pp105)

3. Если оборот с повторяющимся словом **присоединяется союзом И,** то перед союзом ставится **запятая**, а при подчеркивании присоединяемой конструкции — **тире**: Суд руководствуется законом, и только законом; Ты, и только ты можешь сделать это; Да, и только да!; Факты, и только факты могут подтвердить сказанное; В этом, и только в этом заключается правда; Это была победа — и важная победа; Он выигрывал — и как выигрывал!

Но (**без интонации присоединения**): Через три точки, не принадлежащие одной прямой, проходит одна и только одна плоскость.

**Примечание**

1. Лучше написать так:   *Нужно писать кеш, и только кеш: буква Э после согласных **редко когда** пишется.*

Сочетание ***очень нечасто*** [в Нацкорпусе](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkkqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJgokCiIKA3JlcRIbChnQvtGH0LXQvdGMINC90LXRh9Cw0YHRgtC%2BMAE=)  — только 7 примеров, в отличие от ***очень редко.***

2. Вообще говоря, с точки зрения **семантики** сообщение желательно записать так: *Нужно писать кеш, и только кеш: выбор гласной контролируется по словарю. Буква Э после согласных редко когда пишется.*